# Android - Start Timer in Notification Bar

Tags: android, timer, notifications, android-intent

I'd like to be able to start a `notification`, specifically a **timer** with an alarm when it is exhausted, from my application.

I searched around for how to start the timer `intent` but can't find anything. Does anyone have an idea on how this can be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AlarmManager is useful for this kinds of things:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: If I set the alarm manager though my app is still required to be running for it to execute right?

Comment: no, actually the alarm manager will create your activity or service and deliver the alarm to it if it's not running.